# Material-UI: the value provided `undefined` to the Tabs component is invalid

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am not having this warning probably on the normal functioning of the app but I am having this problem in the unit tests. So I am doing a unit test for a Tabs component and it gives me the following warning:

[image]

my jsx file looks like this:

```
class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(value);
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, selectedChannelIndex } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs
            key={selectedChannelIndex}
            value={selectedChannelIndex}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            classes={{ root: classes.tabsRoot, indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}
          >
            {CHANNELS_ARRAY &&
              CHANNELS_ARRAY.map((channel, i) => (
                <Tab
                  key={i}
                  value={i}
                  label={channel.channel}
                  classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
                />
              ))}
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <TabContainer>{this.props.children}</TabContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTabs);
```

and my unit test file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

import Tabs from '../../../src/components/common/Tabs/Tabs';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const defaultProps = { selectedChannelIndex: 0, value: 0, selectInput: 0 };

const setup = (props = {}) => {
  const setupProps = { ...defaultProps, ...props };
  return shallow(<Tabs {...setupProps} />);
};

describe('Tabs', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Tabs {...defaultProps} />);

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(Tabs).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const tree = mount(<Tabs />);
    expect(shallowToJson(tree)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I've seen others asking about this warning as well but many times it's said that to add the value on the tabs element is the solution but is not working for me.

Comment: where are you getting CHANNELS_ARRAY from? what is its value?

Comment: @FahadFarooq, export const CHANNELS_ARRAY = Object.freeze([
  { id: 0, channel: 'voice' },
  { id: 1, channel: 'chat' },
]);